# The crown-based power $L_k$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

Let $L$ be a non-cyclic finite group which has only one minimal normal subgroup, $M$, and  $M$ is either non-abelian or complemented in $L$. Let $k$ be a positive integer and consider the subgroup $$L_k=\{(l_1,...,l_k) \in L^k\mid l_1 \equiv \cdots \equiv l_k \bmod M \}$$ of the direct product $L^k$. Show that the quocient group of $L_{k+1}$ over any minimal normal subgroup is isomorphic to $L_k$.

$\textbf{My attempt}$: I have shown that the direct factors of $M^{k+1}$ are minimal normal subgroups of $L_{k+1}$. In the case where $M$ is non-abelian, these are the only ones, so it is easy to show the isomorphism. Now, when $M$ is abelian, I couldn't do it.